How To Get Nested TaskItem Metadata Values in MSBuild File?
I have an MSBuild TaskItem that contains metadata gathered from a JSON configuration. An example of a single piece of metadata would be
%(Configuration.Object:Name)

and in the case of arrays would be
%(Configuration.Object:Name:0)
%(Configuration.Object:Name:1)
...

When attempting to get this key though, MSBuild is just giving me the exact string instead of interpreting it into the value. Seems as though it can't interpret the colon in the MSBuild file but I've confirmed that the value is present in the metadata by passing the entire TaskItem, @(Configuration), into a custom task. I've also tried to use transform syntax to no avail.
What is the syntax to retrieve these values in the MSBuild file?

I figured it out for all you devs from the future. The answer is Item Functions.
@(Configuration->Metadata('Object:Name'))


Item metadata is not "nested". It's a dictionary of name/value pairs where the name and the value are strings. Your "nesting" is by interpreting the name as a path. @(Configuration->Metadata('Object:Name')) will return the values of the 'Object:Name' metdata for all items in the item collection. You don't mention what package or custom code you are using to map the JSON to the Item collection. Do you have an option to use a different delimiter for the levels of your structure? Can you use a - in place of the :? If you want to be able to batch, you need names that don't use the :.

The JSON is mapped using the IConfigurationBuilder class under Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. I wrote a custom task that that pulls in configuration values, flattens the data (using AsEnumerable ) and then maps the key values as metadata on the output TaskItem.  When I say "nested", I meant nested as JSON but yes you are correct, the metadata is actually flat.

For your specific case if all the JSON paths added to the Configuration item collection will always be unique, then breaking the ability to batch is perhaps an acceptable trade-off.

Essentially metadata names should be valid XML element names with a further constraint that metadata names should not use a period (because the period is used as part of the MSBuild syntax). If you need batching to function, then within your custom task, change the path delimiter from a colon to a hyphen or an underscore, e.g. %(Configuration.Object-Name-0). If the same or a different task creates JSON from an Item collection, a Object-Name-0 path can be converted to Object:Name:0.  (But this will mean the JSON can't have names with hyphens.)

Thanks Jon! That's an amazing idea. Since all of the keys are predefined I'll have some control over that. The framework will be extensible but I can just document the caveat that configuration keys must not be kebab-case :)

Using colons in metadata names can be problematic because MSBuild does not natively handle them well when referenced directly in this syntax. It interprets the part after the colon as a target framework or other suffix, not as part of the metadata name.
To work around this issue, you can use a custom task or inline task within your MSBuild script to properly handle metadata names that contain colons.

The item functions are able to accept the colon and return a value. Refer to my answer above.

@KenGarrett The item functions (including the Metadata function) operate on the entire item collection. When there are multiple members of the collection with the same metadata, all values are returned, i.e. 'Object:Name' can return a list of names. Your specific use case may be constrained so that this is not an issue but for other uses cases the Metadata function may not be useable.

You know that's an interesting tidbit. That wouldn't apply to me in this particular case as all of my values are meant to be predefined unique keys (although I'm also pulling in values from other external sources like key vaults for instance). But I will keep that in mind for future use cases. I'm writing an entire build&deploy framework on top of MSBuild so may need to use it in different ways.
